# Having trouble finding the Big-Oh value

Tags: big-o

Please refer to the code fragment below:

```
sum = 0; 
for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    for( j = 0; j < i * i; j++ ) 
        for( k = 0; k < j; k++ ) 
            sum++;
```

If one was to analyze the run-time of this fragment in Big-Oh Notation, what would be the most appropriate value? Would it be O(N^4)?

Answer (score 0):

I have to say `O(n^5)`. I maybe wrong. `n` is the length of the array in this question I am assuming. If you substitute it, `i` will stop when `i < n` j will stop when `j < n*n` and `k` will stop when `k < n * n`. Since these are nested `for-loops`, the run time is `O(n^5)`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's O(n^5)

We know that

1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = n(n+1) / 2 = O(n^2)

1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1) / 6 = O(n^3)

I think that similary statement is true for sum of bigger powers.

Let's think about these two lines

```
for( j = 0; j < i * i; j++ ) 
        for( k = 0; k < j; k++ )
```

This loop's time complexity for fixed i is 
1 + 2 + ... + (i-1)^2 = (i-1)^2(1 + (i-1)^2) / 2 = O(i^4)

But in our code i changes from 0 to n-1, so we like add fourth powers, and as I said before

1^k + 2^k + ... + n^k = O(n^(k+1))

That's why time complexity is O(n^5)

Answer (score 0):

Given this code, consider each loop separately.

```
sum = 0;
for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )         //L1
    for( j = 0; j < i * i; j++ ) //L2
        for( k = 0; k < j; k++ ) //L3
            sum++;               //
```

Consider the outermost loop (L1) alone. Clearly this loop is O(n).

```
for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )         //L1
    L2(i);
```

Consider the next loop (L2). This one is harder, but the loop is O(n^2).
See this SO answer for why the loop is O(n^2): [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it?rq=1)

```
    for( j = 0; j < i * i; j++ ) //L2
        L3(j);
```

Consider the next loop (L3). Since you know that the L2 loop is O(N^2), what is this loop? (leaving reader to complete their homework).

```
        for( k = 0; k < j; k++ ) //L3
            sum++;               //
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Solution to the problem]

You need some understanding of mathematics to solve this problem. Use Summation techniques and formulas for sum of integers. I myself do not know the summation formula of i^4, but I guessed it would be a polynomial, with the highest ordered term being of 5th order, which means it is O(n^5)